# Problem with Clusters in NodeJS app + Socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, cluster-computing

I was planning to optimize my Node.js application to distribute the load across all CPU cores, as a Node.js application can only utilize a single core. However, by using clusters, we can make use of all the cores
Here is configuration of my Nodejs APP with Clusters:

```
var cluster = require('cluster');
var numCPUs = require('os').cpus().length;
var io = [];
var options = {
    key: fss.readFileSync('/etc/letsencrypt/live/multikpay.ru/privkey.pem'),
    cert: fss.readFileSync('/etc/letsencrypt/live/multikpay.ru/fullchain.pem')
};

if (cluster.isMaster) {
    for (var i = 0; i < numCPUs; i += 1) {
        var worker = cluster.fork();
    }
    
  for (const id in cluster.workers) {
    console.log(`Worker ${id}: ${cluster.workers[id].process.pid}`);
  }

  cluster.on('exit', (worker, code, signal) => {
    console.log(`Worker ${worker.id} died`);
  });
  
} else {
     var express = require('express');
  var app = express();
  var serverPort = 8443;
  var server = https.createServer(options, app);
  var io = require('socket.io')(server, {
    cors: {
      origin: "*",
      methods: ["GET", "POST"],
      headers: ["Access-control-Allow-Credentials", true],
      allowedHeaders: ["content-type"],
      transports: ['websocket', 'polling'],
      credentials: true
    },
    allowRequest: function(req, callback) {
      callback(null, req.headers.referer);
    },
    allowEIO3: true
  });

  server.listen(serverPort, function () {
      console.log('server up and running at port ' + serverPort + '');
  });


io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    var user = false;
    let address;

    io.sockets.emit('counter', {data: Object.keys(io.sockets.sockets).length});

    socket.on('disconnect', function() {
        io.sockets.emit('counter', {data: Object.keys(io.sockets.sockets).length});
        if (user) delete users[user.id];
    });
});

/// and other code

}
```

So the problem is:

[image]

And before clusters I had the same structure of code which connects to sockets and everything was ok, what I am doing wrong?